# How to change attributes of elements using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I change the attributes of using class name or id name (for example ".testing a") using javascript?
Edit. I worded the question the wrong way. What I mean is I want to change the css of the a class.

```
document.querySelector('.testing a').setAttribute('color','green');
```

Something like above but the above code is not working.

```
<div class="testing">
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: which attribute you want to change

Comment: the "a" element but I want to change it the way I've specified such as ".testing a".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all required elements and use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop to through elements and change `style.color` of element

```js
let elms = document.querySelectorAll('.testing a');
elms.forEach(e => e.style.color = "green")
```

```html
<div class="testing">
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
</div>
```

#### Using jQuery

```js
$('.testing a').css('color','green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testing">
  <a>1</a>
  <a>2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to loop? Can I set the attribute for all of them at once?

Comment: @Andy Brooke You can do that using **jQuery**. I updated the code.With pure js its not possible